# How is this $PATH being set to ruby for new user?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I've been toying with chef, and may have installed ruby along the way. Now I would like to upgrade to ruby 2.0. Anyhow I'm curious what could have caused ruby to be added to the path of all new users? Note: there's no mention of ruby in the new user's .bashrc, .profile, or in the global /etc/environment:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ sudo useradd -m testuser
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ sudo su - testuser
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser testuser 4096 Mar 23 02:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root     4096 Mar 23 02:54 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser 3637 Apr  9  2014 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser  675 Apr  9  2014 .profile
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ echo $PATH
/home/testuser/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/opt/rubies/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:/opt/rubies/1.9.3-p429/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ which ruby
/opt/rubies/1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$
```

I'm at a loss as to where to look to find and remove the references to ruby 1.9.3 being added apparently automatically.

Comment: How did you install ruby?

Comment: Are you using some sort for ruby version manager (e.g. RVM)?

Comment: @Addison sorry, don't remember... orde, "rvm: command not found" rbenv not installed either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out somewhere along the way, somehow, chruby got installed. The quick fix to resolve the user PATH not being overwritten was to disable the .sh chruby put in /etc/profile.d:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:/etc/profile.d$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  663 Aug 19  2015 bash_completion.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  147 Mar 21 00:58 chruby.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1559 Jul 29  2014 Z97-byobu.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2691 Nov 23 18:41 Z99-cloud-locale-test.sh
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:/etc/profile.d$ sudo mv chruby.sh chruby.sh.disabled
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:/etc/profile.d$ ls
bash_completion.sh  chruby.sh.disabled  Z97-byobu.sh  Z99-cloud-locale-test.sh
ubuntu@ip-10-10-10-10:/etc/profile.d$ sudo su - testuser
testuser@ip-10-10-10-10:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Better would be to uninstall chruby, but it's not obvious to me how to do that given I don't know / don't remember how it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Please try with this option  dpkg --get-selections.

As you might be knowing everything is considered as gems. Hence try with this also if above does not work...
$ gem -h
or
$rvm list known
and then you can install only the required version using
rvm install ruby 2.0.0-p247 
REFERNCE:- http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/